# Calculate distances from one list sample to all other list data samples

Tags: python, distance

I have two datasets - one is called unknown_dataset and the other is red_dataset. I need to to compare each element from unknown_dataset to every element in red_dataset. I am comparing distance using the function below:

```
    d = 0 
    for i in range(len(p1)): 
        d += (p2[i] - p1[i]) * (p2[i] - p1[i])  
    d = d**0.5 
    return d
```

Later I will need to find the shortest distance. I have tried creating for loop but it always returns float instead of a list. I would really appreciate any tips, thank you!

Comment: it is not clear the expected output. the list should be of pairs of points from both lists? So, `[(u_point, red_point), ...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your datasets are lists of points in a 2+ dimensional space like for instance:

```
unknown_dataset = [(1,1,1), (2,2,2)]
red_dataset = [(2, 2, 2), (3,3,3)]
```

Then you can solve this with a for loop, as you already suggested:

```
def get_distance(p1, p2):
    d = 0
    for i in range(len(p1)):
        d += (p2[i] - p1[i]) * (p2[i] - p1[i])
    d = d**0.5
    return d

all_distances = []

for p1 in unknown_dataset:
    for p2 in red_dataset:
        distance_p1_p2 = get_distance(p1, p2)
        all_distances.append(distance_p1_p2)
```

where all_distances is the list of distances you are looking for

you would get the shortest distance with:

```
print(min(all_distances))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using numpy for this:

```
import numpy as np

distances = np.sqrt((np.array(p2) - np.array(p1)) ** 2)
print(np.amin(distances))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function return `float` because that's what it does. You should use the [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) built-in together with the `key` parameter to specify a callback function... in this case, given a list of pairs of points take the minimum wrt the `distance` function. Notice the it returns an element of the list not the value of distance.

```
# euclidean distance
def distance(p1, p2):
    return sum((coord1 - coord2)**2 for coord1, coord2  in zip(p1, p2))**.5


# data sets
unknown_dataset = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
red_dataset = [(-2, 5), (9, 9), (0, -10)]

# pairing between the two datasets
pairings = [(u_point, red_point) for u_point in unknown_dataset for red_point in red_dataset]

# get pair of points with minimal distance
nearest_pair = min(pairings, key=lambda p: distance(*p))

# output
print(f'{nearest_pair = }, distance: {distance(*nearest_pair):f}')
# nearest_pair = ((1, 2), (-2, 5)), distance: 4.242641
```